# Preventing attributes update in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model, article, that has two states, `created` and `finalized`. I allow users to create articles but it can only be finalized if certain attributes of the model are present.

State itself is an attribute of my `article.rb` model. Given that in my Controller, I will have strong params, I wanna go even further and prevent that a call update to the object doesn't update the attribute state, but still update other attributes, like the following:

```
article = Article.create!
article.state # => "created"
article.update!(attr1: "attr1", attr2: "attr2", state: "finalized")
article # => attr1: attr2, attr2: attr2, attr3: null, attr4: null, state: "created"
article.update!(attr3:, "attr3", attr4: "attr4", state: "finalized")
article # => attr1: "attr2", attr2: "attr2", attr3: "attr3", 
        #    attr4: "attr4", state: "finalized"
```

My idea is to prevent an attribute of the object being updated unless all the required attributes are present but still allow users to create the object without having to specify all the attributes upfront. How can I achieve this? (And is it worth the trouble, or a good idea?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it by supplying a validation in the model, rather then in controller, like this:

```
class Article
  validates :state, exclusion: { in: %w(finalized) },
            unless: Proc.new { |a| a.attr1.present? && a.attr2.present? }
end
```

You might also consider using state machine to keep track of article's state: https://github.com/aasm/aasm

Comment: agreed, just for the future

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readonly?`

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def readonly?
    state != "finalized"
  end
end
```

Which will raise an exception if you try to update the Article. Wether that is a good design decision or not depends on your domain. In most cases I would use a "published" state and let viewers be able to see any subsequent edits done much like here on StackoverFlow.

The [PaperTrail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) is very useful if you intend to do that sort of tracking.

Comment: Additionally you might want to use [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to keep the states of your model.